# How to break down complex controller methods into parts and execute them in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to break down a complex controller methods into parts and execute them in the rails console in order to see what do they return and how the flow works.

The following example involves:

1. cart creation
2. finding the product
3. line_item creation

**Finding the product in rails console is easy:**

```
2.2.2 :001 > product = Product.find(2)
```

**How to execute this line in the console?**

```
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)
```

It would be better if you can provide me some sources so i can cope with the future scenarios.

**Please See The Implementation Details below** :

Line_item controller :

```
  def create 
      product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @line_item.save
          format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart,
           notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'new' }
        end
     end
  end
```

**cart module concerns**

```
module CurrentCart
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    private

    def set_cart
        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
       @cart = Cart.create
       session[:cart_id] = @cart.id 
    end
end
```

Cart Controller:

```
def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

 private 

def cart_params
 params[:cart]
```

Associassions:

```
Cart has_many :line_items 
product has_many :line_items
Line_items belongs_to :product
Line_items belong_to  :cart
```

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for Code Review Stack Exchange: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jordan Hi Jordan, i realised  that  this topic is not a good fit for Code Review.Im not sure If you noticed the question above "How to execute this line in the console?"

Comment: Why are you trying to execute this in the console?

Comment: @RichPeck Hi Rich. That's a good question . I just want to experiment every single piece of code from the create action. it helps me to visualise the flow , and also get into greater details .

Comment: hmm okay. When using the CLI, every variable has to be defined. You're using `@cart` which means you have to define that. Even then, you're using a `session` which I don't think is supported in the console. I've made a cart app before (you can see at http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com) which uses a similar setup. I can post code if required

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did define @cart . the controller code has been included above . However,  i think i have figured out how to execute them in the console .  The way i did is to breakdown "@cart.line_items.build(product: product)"  into two parts .  Firstly create a new cart object by excuting { cart = Cart.new  save it } . Then create line item object with a separate line { lineitem = cart.line_items.build(product: product) } , lineitem.save . it gets successfully  saved in the database.